# JQuery - Get width: auto from inline style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get an inline property of an element using jquery: `width: auto`.
As soon as I get the width, `.width()` returns a px value instead of `auto`.
This is an example of what I need:

I've an `img` with this inline style setted:

```
<img id='image' style='position: absolute; height: 200px; width: auto; top: 25px; left: 50px;' src='http://tinyurl.com/k8ef66b'/>
```

I need to wrap that image in an `a`, to make the image clickable. I need also to get the image style and move it to the anchor tag:

```
//--- get height, width and entire style
var imgHeight = $("#image").height();
var imgWidth = $("#image").width();
var imgStyle = $("#image").attr("style");

//---remove inline style from the img
$("#image").removeAttr("style");

//--- create the <a>, add the inline style
var anch = $("<a href='#'></a>");
$(anch).attr("style", imgStyle);

//--- add back to the img it's width and height
//--- the problem is here: imgWidth does not contain 'auto'
$("#image").css({"width" : imgWidth, "height" : imgHeight});

//--- wrap the img
$("#image").wrap(anch);
```

here's a fiddle with the code: http://jsfiddle.net/cBXAz/1/

any idea? How can I get the `auto` out of that inline style? I need to give `width: auto` to the image instead of a px value.

Thanks in advance, best regards

Comment: `$("#image").css({"width" : "auto"})`???

Comment: When I look at the fiddle I don't see `height:auto` on the image.

Comment: @KevinBowersox I wrote "width: auto", not "height" :)

Comment: @Morpheus I need to get that value from the inline style, I can't set it manyally..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('image').style.width;
```

Or for more jquery's way:

```
$("#image")[0].style.width;
```

Comment: In this case you'll get actual width of image, not `auto` :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JA2ds/  if you use it before changing the width it works for sure

Comment: More jQuery way is `$("#image").width()` or `$("#image").css('width')`

Comment: @jQuery00 i was talking about selector not syntax. Using jquery's width() method will return computed style

Comment: when image render in small than style dont work `$("#image").width()`